# Accepted and upvoted answer ended up being wrong due to SDK bug

Tags: support, voting, accepted-answer

Ages ago I asked a question about leaking code. Got two answers that both seemed right and correct at the time as the issue was undocumented else where.

With the release of a the new SDK it turns out that the problem wasn't with my code and was a fault with the SDK. I posted my answer and can accept this but can't remove my upvote unless their answer changes.

The upvoted answers are now clearly wrong and would lead other uses to the wrong answer as they are higher in the list, but I can't get rid of them. I'm guessing I'm stuck with it though.

Comment: Was it [Memory leak using (void) alloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497404/memory-leak-using-void-alloc)?

Comment: Yup. It's odd I know and I didn't want to change it unless I was absolutely sure but I've done many tests and am 100% positive. Edit: heh, thanks for the up vote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving a comment on the answer indicates this for users new to the question.  If that's not enough for you, a note at the bottom of your question would be more prominent.

You could make a trivial modification (if you have enough rep) and then change your vote, but that would be in poor style here, IMHO.

Comment: Yeah I agree and I don't want to remove other peoples votes as those answers might help them, but their answers threw me off the correct answer and so shouldn't get my up vote.

Answer (score 2):

Can you edit your question to say something like "This question (and the following answers) only applies to SDK v1 and not SDK v2"?

Comment: Good thought and did it. Unfortunately can't remove my up votes but at least people might be less confused.